# How to manually upload rdl file in reporting server in ssrs.

Tags: .net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I'm working on SSRS print. If deploy it directily it is wokring, but if maually upload the deployed RDL file in reporting server then i'm getting exception

"One or more data source credentials required to run the report have not been specified. (rsCredentialsNotSpecified)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this site](http://ok-sandbox.com/2013/12/ssrs-fix-rsinvaliddatasourcereference/)

> Data Source has no unique property which could be defined by developer or SSRS Administrator... By the way, report does not have that either. Only combination of Path and Name makes Report or Data Source unique within SSRS deployment. Thus, when you deploy or re-deploy either Report or Shared Data Source, you have to establish or re-establish the reference.

As you are only doing one side of this deployment when uploading a file the connection to the data source is lost.You then have to manually reconnect the report back to the data source.The following is taken from [MSDN](http://ok-sandbox.com/2013/12/ssrs-fix-rsinvaliddatasourcereference/)

1. Start Report Manager
2. In Report Manager, navigate to the Contentspage. Navigate to the report that you want to configure a report-specific data source for, and open the report.
3. Click the Properties tab. The Generalproperties page opens.
4. Click the Data Sources tab. This opens the Data Source properties page of the report.

You can then assign an uploaded /configured data source from the report server to your report.